# Is there a command to see who owns an Internet domain?

Tags: command-line, internet, dns, whois

Is there a command to see who owns a specific Internet domain address?

I have tried with `whois example.com` and I get some information. But for "holder" there is just a "user ID".  Is there any way to see who the actual user is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`whois` is definitely the command to use.

In some cases however the owner of the internet address chooses to withhold this information. For some [TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) this is not allowed.

`whois example.com` is an unusual special case. However try something like `whois ubuntu.com` - this clearly gives you a name, physical address, email address and phone number.

Comment: that creepy did a search on mine. it shows my address!

Comment: I recommend this tool http://www.apps-tube.com/whois/

Answer (score 1):

There are several whois services with different results (e.g. try online searches). In addition, there are paid services for hiding the real owner of a domain inquestion. Therefore owners can not be displayed for some domains.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any command to find who owns a specific Internet domain address. But there is a way to find the owner of any website (domain) through Internet using [Whoisxy.com](http://www.whoisxy.com). This gives the current owner of the domain, administrative and technical contact details etc....